# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I am using Eclipse and making a Web Dynamic Project using Hibernate JPA Annotation:

When I run my project, it gives me the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate
```

I included the `MySQL connector jar` file under `web-inf/lib` folder.

Any suggestions??

Comment: How do I register the driver?

Comment: As an aside tip, drivers are normally provisioned. IE: They sit with other common libraries in the web container (eg: with Tomcat this is the lib directory).

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson I forgot to register Driver :)

Comment: @Holger: What is "grammer"? :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A typo